# ¿Cómo incorporar una pausa de n segundos en una animación?

Tags: r, gif, imagemagick

Estoy trabajando con animaciones de series temporales en un bucle de [i]. Mi código funciona bien animando y acumulando puntos en una línea ggplot. Sin embargo, no puedo encontrar la manera de detener la animación al final del ciclo 10 segundos hasta que la animación se reinicie nuevamente para ver las tramas con claridad. No sé si el problema está en la función FUN () o en la herramienta saveGif.

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(animation)
library(rasterVis)
library(gridExtra)
library(xts)
library(rgdal)

f<-read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
date <- xts(f$Fecha, as.Date(f$Fecha, "%d-%m-%Y"))

library(animation)
# Sys.getenv("PATH", "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8")
ani.options(convert = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8\\convert.exe')

FUN <- function() {
  lapply(732:length(date), function(i) {
      gg1<-ggplot(f[732:i,, drop=FALSE],aes(y=SCA,x=Dia.juliano)) +  ggtitle("Cobertura nival") + 
            xlab("Días") + ylab(expression("SCA"~(km^2)))+geom_line(colour="deepskyblue2",size=1)+ theme_classic()+
            scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(min(f$Dia.juliano), max(f$Dia.juliano),by=30),lim=c(min(f$Dia.juliano), max(f$Dia.juliano)))+ theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14,colour= "black"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size = 12,colour="black",face="bold"),plot.margin = margin(0, 1, 1, 0, "cm"),axis.title.x = element_text(size=12))+
            scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,8500,by=2000),lim=c(min(f$SCA), max(f$SCA)))
      gg2<-ggplot(f[732:i,, drop=FALSE],aes(y=Caudal,x=Dia.juliano)) +  ggtitle("Caudal") +
            xlab("Días") + ylab(expression("Caudal"~(m^3/s^-1)))+geom_line(colour="mediumaquamarine",size=1)+ theme_classic()+
            scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(min(f$Dia.juliano), max(f$Dia.juliano),by=30),lim=c(min(f$Dia.juliano), max(f$Dia.juliano)))+ theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14,colour= "black"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size = 12,colour="black",face="bold"),plot.margin = margin(0, 1, 1, 0, "cm"),axis.title.x = element_text(size=12))+
            scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,2500,by=500),lim=c(min(f$Caudal), max(f$Caudal)))   
    grid.arrange(gg1,gg2, ncol=2,nrow=1,top="")
    animation::ani.pause()
  })
}


type <- if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") shell else system
saveGIF(FUN(),interval = 0.3, outdir = getwd(), cmd.fun = type,ani.width=1024, ani.height=600,movie.name="serie.gif")
```

[image: Output gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he encontrado ninguna opción en la documentación de `animate` para configurar una pausa, pero ya que necesitas `imagemagick` para generar la animación, nada te impide usarlo para modificar la animación ya realizada. Algo como esto:

```
segundos <- 5
cmd <- paste(ani.options("convert"), 
             file.path(getwd(),"serie.gif"),
             ifelse(Sys.info()[['sysname']] == "Linux",paste('\\( +clone -set delay', segundos * 100, '\\)'), paste('( +clone -set delay', segundos * 100, ')')),
             ' +swap +delete',
             file.path(getwd(),"new.serie.gif")
             )
system(cmd)
```

[Aquí](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16876) tienes el comando que en definitiva se debe ejecutar para modificar lo que pides. El siguiente es un ejemplo distinto al tuyo pero que sirve como demostración:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(animation)
library(gganimate)

ani.options(ani.height = 200, ani.width = 600, interval = 0.1)
ani.options(convert = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8\\convert.exe')

# Creamos una nueva columna para establecer los bloques de datos
# que entrarán en cada frame del Gif. Numero chico = animación lenta
economics$frame <- as.integer(1:nrow(economics) / 10)  

p <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, psavert, frame = frame, cumulative = TRUE)) +
    geom_line()

gganimate(p, title_frame = FALSE, filename="serie.gif")

segundos <- 5
cmd <- paste(ani.options("convert"), 
             file.path(getwd(),"serie.gif"),
             ifelse(Sys.info()[['sysname']] == "Linux",paste('\\( +clone -set delay', segundos * 100, '\\)'), paste('( +clone -set delay', segundos * 100, ')')),
             ' +swap +delete',
             file.path(getwd(),"new.serie.gif")
             )
system(cmd)
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente, era lo que necesitaba. Gracias